# What is the correct way to use a SearchBar with NSFetchedResultsController and NSPredicate with Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using a fetchedResultsController to populate a tableview with a list of names.  When the view loads, the tableView populates correctly, using the names stored in Core Data.

```
func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Respondent> = Respondent.fetchRequest()
    let lastSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "last", ascending: true)
    let firstSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "first", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [lastSort, firstSort]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "firstCache")

    controller.delegate = self

    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print ("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Showing on device:
[image]

The problem I'm having is that when I use the searchBar function to search for the first name, and use this text to set the predicate, the performFetch fails, indicating that I've given an invalid argument.  The following is my function:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if let textInSearchBar = searchBar.text {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Respondent> = Respondent.fetchRequest()

        //set up sortDescriptor for fetch
        let lastSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "last", ascending: true)
        let firstSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "first", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [lastSort, firstSort]

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "first contains[c] %@", textInSearchBar)

        fetchRequest.predicate = searchPredicate

        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        controller.delegate = self

        self.controller = controller

        do {
            try self.controller.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let error = error as NSError
            print ("\(error)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

2018-12-08 15:33:09.100555-0700 soft touch[83481:3507366] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:  , unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (FIRST CONTAINS[c] "John") (bad RHS) with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:  , unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (FIRST CONTAINS[c] "John") (bad RHS) with userInfo of (null)
2018-12-08 15:33:09.115905-0700 soft touch[83481:3507366] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (FIRST CONTAINS[c] "John") (bad RHS)'

This is puzzling to me because I've gone over how to create the predicate and I think I've created it correctly.  I also know that I do have, in the my Respondent core data class the String attribute of first:
[image]

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: `first` is a reserved word (so is `last`) so CD is getting confused parsing your predicate.  Try changing the attribute name.  (See the very bottom of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) for details of reserved words.

Comment: Thanks, when I changed out these reserved words it worked correctly.